# Code or command-line for converting ODG (open document graphic) to PNG, JPEG, etc? (Windows and/or macOS)

Tags: libreoffice, openoffice.org

I've spent many hours searching for open-source code or utilities (other than the full LibreOffice suite) that would let me convert an ODG (Open Document Graphic) image to any standard format like PNG or JPEG. I'm hoping to find such a tool for both Windows and macOS, but would be grateful to have a tool for one or the other if I can't have both.

I know that I can install LibreOffice and run `soffice -headless -invisible -convert-to` etc. to do this job, and I know that it can be done with LibreOffice running as a service. But I'm trying to find something that I can distribute to other users without requiring them to install LibreOffice (or some earlier equivalent like OpenOffice, etc.).

I also know that many online converters exist, but I am looking for a command-line tool that won't expose a user's files to third parties who may snoop on the data.

Does such a command-line tool or library exist?

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion of a viewer method. I'm still looking for a command-line converter (not a viewer), but, as you say, it doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: Thank you again. I'm looking for something that I can distribute to other users. I've written a utility (in AutoIt) that uses a reduced uninstalled copy of LibreOffice, but it's immense, and it would be nice to have something compact. Clearly, though, it does not exist. Thank you for this.

Comment: The reduced-LibreOffice utility I wrote (for converting WordPerfect documents to DOCX) is here: http://www.columbia.edu/~em36/wpdos/converttoword.html#wplo I wrote it a few years ago, so it may use version 5 or 6 or LibreOffice - I've simply forgotten. I didn't reduce it as aggressively as I know I could have done.

Comment: I'm not being naive, but what are you referring to with "xchange viewer /GS"? I've written software that uses PDFXchange Editor, but I don't know what "/GS" refers to - maybe Ghostscript?. I'm genuinely puzzled.

Comment: And I wonder what could possibly be "infamous" about those programs. They seem fairly innocent to me.

Answer (score 0):

Please try command line in form

```
soffice --headless --nologo --nofirststartwizard --norestore  --convert-to jpg:draw_jpg_Export "full_path_and_filename_source_draw_document.odg" --outdir path_to_output_folder
```

Name of filter can be `draw_png_Export` or [**any other**](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/what-are-the-5-x-graphics-import-export-filters/15180?u=johnsun)

Comment: Thank you - but the question asked for a solution that did NOT require the user to install LibreOffice. I am trying to create a utility that users can download and use without having LibreOffice. As far as I can tell, the command line that you offered requires LibreOffice to be installed.