# Is there a way to automatically export OpenOffice/LibreOffice drawings to bitmaps, with options?

Tags: graphics, bitmap, export, libreoffice, openoffice.org

I have some drawings in multi-paged .ODG files. I would like to have a way to automatically export them to bitmaps, with a controlled set of export options.

I'd like the exported format to be PNG or equivalent.
Apache OpenOffice or LibreOffice makes no difference. An extension to any of those would be acceptable.

Specifically, I'd like to be able to set, at the very least:

- a page in the drawing file;
- export of 'selection only' (and to 'select all' on that page);
- bitmap dimensions.

Comment: What is your specific question? From the title there is a literal answer: Yes,most probably.

Comment: Okay, thank you, so what is the way then? A software tool, an algorithm? Something that can be freely downloaded and maybe hacked a bit to fit? I've tried search engines first, of course.

Comment: You might want to read some pages of the [help], for example "[ask]". Recommendations are off-topic here. StackOverflow is not a forum. Sorry.

Comment: I see tons of questions on these sites which should be answered by RTFM or belong to forums. Not much chiding *there*. I don't want 'recommendations', I want sort of everyday StackOverflow's pattern of answers, some of which, while not quite answering the issue, may point me in the right direction.

Comment: To me your post asks for recommendations. These are problematic because of their opinionated nature, and are therefore not on-topic. Especially "_the right direction_"<TM> is commonly opinionated. -- Please [edit] your question to show your attempt, the programming language you want to use, what you have tried so far, and so on. -- You might want to take the [tour] to learn more how this site works. ;-)

Comment: To me this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76054978/code-or-command-line-for-converting-odg-open-document-graphic-to-png-jpeg-et disproves your statement.

Comment: Just because people break the rules does not mean it is OK to break the rules. To me it is not the way questions are asked and answered, but the documented rules. :-) Go ahead, provide the additional information needed to make this on-topic, or change the wording so that it does not ask for recommendations, and everything is good. Why spend so much time to reason to not do it?